# Fitting polynomials with degree>2 using fminunc

Tags: matlab, least-squares, polynomial-approximations

I am trying to find the coefficients for polynomials of degree `n` using `fminunc`. I know `polyfit` but I have to use fminunc (or lsqnonlin) because I need to extend my model at a later point. Anyway, my objective function is simply the nonlinear least-square problem and I applied the same centering and scaling approach used by `polyfit`:

```matlab
tmpx = (xdat-mean(xdat))./std(xdat) % centering/scaling
x0 = zeros(degree+1, 1); % initial point
objfctn = @(pars) mdl(pars, tmpx, ydat)
```

with

```matlab
function [ sse, grad ] = mdl( pars, xdat, ydat )
    est = polyval(pars, xdat)-ydat;
    sse = sum(est.^2);

    degree = length(pars)-1;

    grad = [];
    for d = 0:degree
        grad = [sum(2*est.*(xdat.^d)); grad]; %#ok<AGROW>
    end
end
```

I then generated some test data according to some heuristics derived from my target measurement data set:

```matlab
degree = 2;
tpars = [ ... % true parameters
    randraw('uniform', [-5e-20, 5e-20], 1), ...
    randraw('uniform', [-10e-20, 10e-20], 1), ...
    randraw('uniform', [-20e-9, 20e-9], 1), ...
    randraw('uniform', [-50e-6, 50e-6], 1), ...
    randraw('uniform', [0, 89e9], 1)];
tpars = tpars(end-degree:end);
xdat = sort(randi(1800e9, 100e3, 1));
yreal = polyval(tpars, xdat);
ydat = yreal + randraw('norm', [0, 100], length(xdat));
```

with the famous `randraw` script available [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7309-randraw).

So far so good, this works well for polynomials of degree up to 2 (i.e., `length(pars) <= 3`). With the above test data, it even beats `polyfit` in accuracy. However, as soon as I try to fit a polynomial with degree higher than 2, `fminunc` stops right after the initial iteration saying

> Optimization stopped because the objective function cannot be decreased in the current search direction. Either the predicted change in the objective function, or the line search interval is less than eps.

However, `polyfit` is still able to fit the polynomial, although with an increasing error. Anyone any idea how to fit higher degree polynomials with `fminunc`?

My feeling is that some numerical issue prevents `fminunc` from doing its job. Maybe the gradients are too high and I need some y-axis scaling as well?

Comment: I'm curious what you mean this method "beats `polyfit` in accuracy"? By definition, `polyfit` "is a best fit (in a least-squares sense)", so you're simply using a different accuracy metric to the one `polyfit` optimises to?

Comment: By beating `polyfit` I mean that the root-mean-square deviation from the true polynomial is much smaller for `fminunc`-fitted polynomials than for the `polyfit`-fitted ones. For `degree=2` I obtain an average RMSE of 2.1334 for `fminunc` and 45.4157 for `polyfit`.

Comment: Just checked: for degree=1, both approaches have the exact same performance over 50 runs. So maybe another numerical issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my guess with the y-axis scaling was right and `fminunc` seems to have some numerical issues if the SSE is to high. I solved the problem by simply applying the same scaling to the y-axis as I did for the x-axis:

```matlab
scaling_factor = std(ydat);
ydat_scaled = ydat / scaling_factor;
% fit the polynomial to ydat_scaled using fminunc or lsqnonlin
result = result * scaling_factor;
```

I tested this approach with polynomials of degrees up to 4 and it works like a charm. In terms of root-mean-square deviation of the resulting polynomial from the original polynomial, `fminunc` performs much better than polyfit. Specifically, I did 100 runs for each degree 0-4, each run with a new set of test data (see question above). The average RMSE of the 100 runs were:

- degree=0: `avgrmse_fminunc = 0.2608` and `avgrmse_polyfit=0.2608`
- degree=1: `avgrmse_fminunc = 0.3810` and `avgrmse_polyfit=0.3809`
- degree=2: `avgrmse_fminunc = 2.5897` and `avgrmse_polyfit=53.3994`
- degree=3: `avgrmse_fminunc = 34.0733` and `avgrmse_polyfit=340.6380`
- degree=4: `avgrmse_fminunc = 5.2805e+13` and `avgrmse_polyfit=2.9255e+14`

These results suggest that for applications with high SSE values and high accuracy requirements, a "manual" least-square minimization might be preferable.